# Foods other than onions that can be caramelized for a delicious result

Tags: onions, caramelization

Is there a way to caramelize foods other than onions and produce similar results?

Comment: Milk.  aka, Dulce de Leche.

Comment: @Joe Simmer a can of condensed milk (still sealed in the can) for several hours to get the easiest dulce de leche ever.

Comment: Onions are stars in this department, because they're sweet, but I have yet to find a fruit or veggie that doesn't roast or grill well. If you haven't tried cauliflower or broccoli yet, you really should. Cut into bite size pieces and roast with a little oil until brown and crispy all over.

Comment: I've closed this question as a poll. I think there's probably a decent question in here somewhere about what criteria to look for when judging if something will caramelize well or providing some slightly more detailed criteria than "orgasmicness", but as is it's just a poll (as evidenced by the answers). The question can be reopened if it is 'fixed'. See the [FAQ] if there are any other questions.

Comment: @yossarian A poll is a question that asks for votes. This is not a poll, since im not asking people to vote on the best food to caramelize. My question isn't "what criteria to look for when judging if something will caramelize well'' as you put it. It's a simple, answerable question: Which foods return delicious results if you caramelize them? That is a cooking method/technique question, and ive had great responses so far. As for 'orgasmicness', it's called humor and it makes reading more enjoyable.

Comment: I can appreciate that you're not accustomed to our definition of "poll", but for reference, poll questions on the SE network are those that primarily solicit answers and answer votes based on personal preference, as opposed to their thoroughness or overall quality/correctness. You didn't specify the options up-front, but it's still a poll. It's definitely not a question about technique. Please also keep in mind that not everybody will appreciate your humour; I didn't personally have any problem with it, but as a rule of thumb, it's best to keep your questions straight and to-the-point.

Comment: FAQ------If you have a question about:

Cooking & food preparation methods
Kitchen equipment
Food handling and storage
Ingredient selection and use
Recipe comprehension, improvement, and repairs
...then you've come to the right place - we want to help you! - FAQ----- @aaronut Where should i have asked this question? Another website? I understand you want this to be the best website it can be. How could I have asked this question better?

Comment: @Kewigro: A better way to ask this question might have been to give more specific context, maybe explain what dish your cooking. I see some people have answered "apples" and someone else answered "parsnips" and I'm sure that they are both good answers, but maybe not for the same kind of dish.

Comment: @kewigro, the key is that the question needs to warrant a definitive answer or two. The question you have asked could be an endless list of items. What you need to do is focus the question a little bit so that people can provide definitive answers. You could do this by asking about the criteria for caramalization (which would essentially answer your question) or providing a specific context on which to judge answers. As is, almost any answer is equally valid, so the question is not a good fit for our site.

Answer (score 1):

Caramelized apples: http://www.seasaltwithfood.com/2010/10/french-toast-with-caramelized-apples.html or carrots: http://www.kayotic.nl/blog/caramelized-carrots-2 are delicious. Give them a go.

Answer (score 1):

garlic, peppers, mushrooms, cabbage....

Answer (score 0):

Parsnips are definitely one, in fact, I wouldn't eat them any other way than roasted. Put them quartered in the oven (coated in goose fat) at 220C for around 40 minutes until golden brown.